# sub versioning with a TSQL Mac osX client

Tags: macos, mac, svn, ms-sql

How can i setup ANY t-sql mac client connecting to a ms sql server and connect it to our svn server? i am looking to mimic MS Management studio + red gate. where once you have added the SVN link you can begin comparing the DB, making commits and pull request. I am unsure how to do this on a mac.

i am currently demoing
smartsvn for a svn
and
razorsql and 'mac sql client' for the tsql clients.

**Edit:**
after testing some mac ms sql clients,
My actual requirements is a OSX client that can open up a .mdf file and manage the database on the mac. razorsql will only connect to an existing sql server. The only one up is the live server. Then i can use an appropriate svn client to perform commits and pulls from the source server

Answer (score -1):

Can't merge the two direct, but can gather data and reformat (source Ctrl) so it can talk to the other end.

Tortoise SVN plugin.

Subversion source-control

Subversion seems really solid, it's quite fast, and has lots of 3rd-party plugins.

Comment: which i am sort of doing, with the smartsvn. it does detect the repository changes from the server. but since i haven't got a t-sql answer i can't test any or my commits. Razorsql only remotely connected to a ms sql, the problem right now is i do not have a remote/network ms sql server other than the live db to connect to so i can't test. I was hopeful that there was a ms sql client for the mac that allowed local MS SQL DB creation.